enrichKegg arbitrarily excluding certain genes from gene set during analysis
I'm using the R-package enrichKEGG to perform an enrichment analysis on a vector of genes. As output I get a list of pathways containing some number of the genes in my vector. In the results there is a 'GeneRatio' column that shows how many of the genes in your vector appeared in each pathway.
My problem: My input vector contains 101 genes, but the GeneRatios for all the found pathways have 54 as the denominator (some of the ratios are: 12/54, 7/54, 8/54), suggesting that enrichKEGG is discarding nearly half of the genes in my vector before performing the analysis.
Ive tried adjusting every parameter: setting the pvaluecutoff and qvaluecutoff to 1, setting the minimum gene size to 1 and the maximum gene size to 10000, but its still 54 genes.
One possibility is that the ENTREZ-ids of some of the genes in my vector simply do not appear in any pathways. But I've looked at some of the genes that appear in the input-vector and don't appear in the list of 54 genes used in the analysis, and when I search those ids with (https://www.genome.jp/kegg/mapper/search.html) I find loads of results for pathways that the genes appear in.
Some of the genes that appear in the input vector AND in the list of 54 (ENTREZ ids):
"9319"   "10403"  "1026"   "9088"   "891"    "9700"   "890"    "113130" "9133"   "995"    "983"    "9212"   "3479"   "51512"

Some of the genes that appear in the input vector but DON'T appear in the list of 54 (ENTREZ ids):
"5980"   "3479"   "9319"   "51512"  "27092"  "27244"  "10403"  "8438"   "332"    "24137"  "4605"   "8411"   "2146"   "51655"

I'd really like to know based on what condition nearly half the genes are excluded from the analysis.

I'd suggest this is a ln2 cut-off which is not being cleared, this isn't dependent on probability but what is biologically reasonable before assessing a probability. This cut-off should be in the documentation. KEGG is very comprehensive db and 50% absence doesn't correlate with my experience, which even in massively diverse metagenomics data never rises above 40% against NCBI (i.e. worse case scenario). There's not really enough information to answer the question beyond this IMHO.
